# No builder returned for name: vagrant Packer.io error

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, json, packer

I just want to provision a standard Ubuntu 12.04 image with a shell script, and then package it so I can use it with Vagrant. This is the configuration I wrote:

```
{
  "builders": [{
        "type": "vagrant",
        "iso_url": "http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.3-server-amd64.iso",
        "iso_checksum": "2cbe868812a871242cdcdd8f2fd6feb9",
        "iso_checksum_type": "md5"
    }],

    "provisioners": [{
        "type": "shell",
        "script": "bootstrap.sh"
    }],

    "post-processors": ["vagrant"]
}
```

Unfortunately 'packer validate packer.json' throws me the following error: 'No builder returned for name: vagrant

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The builder "type" needs to be a valid Packer builder value. There is no vagrant builder. Are you trying to create a standalone box that is not using VirtualBox, VMWare or Amazon?

This page provides more builder information:

http://www.packer.io/docs/templates/builders.html